# Tangent space basis of $S^3 \times S^3$

Tags: differential-topology, tangent-spaces

I am working with the group morphism $\rho: S^3 \times S^3 \rightarrow SO(4)$ where $\rho(q,r)x = qxr^{-1}$ for $q,r \in S^3$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^4$ and trying to compute the differential of this map at the identity, namely $\rho_{*,(1,1)}$, and show it is an isomorphism. I am trying to compute the Jacobian needed, by finding a basis of the tangent space in $SO(4)$ which I already have and a basis for the tangent space of the product $S^3 \times S^3$ and filling out the Jacobian as appropriately. However, I am having trouble understandin how a vector in the tangent space of $S^3 \times S^3$ at the identity would look like and how I could find a basis of this vector space. Can anyone help me with how I should think of the vector elements in $T_{1}S^3 \times T_{1}S^3 $ in order to find the desired Jacobian? Thanks!

Comment: It should $T_1S^3\times T_1S^3$ not $T_{(1,1)}S^3\times T_{(1,1)}S^3$.  Think of $S^3$ as the unit quaternions, and there is a natural identification $T_1S^3$ with $\operatorname{Im}\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: So the way I computed the tangent basis of $S^3$ at the identity before was by considering the map $\phi(a +bi +cj+dk) = \left( \begin{matrix} a - bi & -(c+di) \\ c-di & a + bi \end{matrix} \right)$ where I ended up getting that the basis is the matrices $\left( \begin{matrix}0 & i \\ i & 0   \end{matrix}\right)$, $\left( \begin{matrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0   \end{matrix}\right)$, $\left( \begin{matrix}i & 0 \\ 0 & -i   \end{matrix}\right)$

Comment: From there, I am not sure how to use that basis of $T_1S^3$. Any further comments I would really appreciate! Plus, You are right about the notation, I fixed it.

Comment: I should mention that my intution would tell me that we have 9 basis vectors in $T_1S^3 \times T_1S^3$, just by counting the possible combinations of the basis vectors I found above. But I know this can't be because we have an isomorphism between $T_1S^3 \times T_1S^3$ and $so(4)$ where the last vector space has dimension 6.

Comment: Those matrices are not a basis for $T_1S^3$.  They are the image of that basis under the differential $dF_1$ where $F:S^3\to\mathfrak{su}(2)$.  The basis you want is $\{i, j, k\}$.

Comment: Also, I believe we are in the same class (591 at UM) and that this question comes from the homework.  I think this question is fine -- it's just asking for help with a small bit of the homework that was due this morning -- but you should know that there's some bad history with math.se and the 59x sequences: https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2012/03/13/cheating-on-homework-in-a-graduate-course-is-staggeringly-dumb/

Comment: Finally, you do *not* want to calculate the Jacobian.  That hardly even makes sense since the columns in question would actually be $4\times 4$ matrices (or you have to pick a basis for $SO(4)$, which just complicates the calculations further).  Instead calculate the action of $d\rho$ on the basis of $T_{(1, 1)}S^3\times S^3$ and show that the image of the basis is a linearly independent set.  Then you can argue by dimension that $d\rho$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

You have a vector space $V \times W$. (In your case, $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic, but I'm gonna talk about the general case for clarity).

You have a basis $v_1, v_2, v_3$ for $V$, and a similar basis for $W$.

Your conjecture, I think, is that a basis for $V \times W$ consists of all pairs
$$
(v_i, w_j)
$$
where $i, j = 1, 2, 3$.

The correct claim is that 
$$
(v_1, 0), (v_2, 0), (v_3, 0), (0, w_1), (0, w_2), (0, w_3)
$$
constitute a basis; the vector $(v, w)$ can be expressed in this basis by writing each of $v$ and $w$ in the respective bases:
$$
v = a_1v_1 + \ldots + a_3 v_3\\
w = b_1w_1 + \ldots + b_3 w_3
$$
Once you've done that, you have

$$
(v, w) = a_1(v_1, 0) + a_2(v_2, 0) + a_3(v_3, 0) + b_1(0, w_1) + b_2(0, w_2) + b_3 (0, w_3).
$$

Perhaps the key point hiding in here is that there's a nice isomorphism between 
$$
T_{q,r}(S^3 \times S^3)
$$
and
$$
T_q(S^3) \times T_r(S^3)
$$
which lets you consider the latter vector space rather than the former. The isomorphism is induced by the projections on the two factors.